# learning to do a discord bot but when i type the command it wont work

Tags: python, discord, bots

my code is below, but when i type !deaths in discord, it doesn't send, the bot is online and everything and visual studio code doesn't give any errors

```
`import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!deaths'):
        try:
            with open('/deaths.txt', 'r') as file:
                contents = file.read()
            await message.channel.send(contents)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            await message.channel.send('File not found!')
client.run('TOKEN')`
```

tried typing !deaths but didn't get a resualt, was trying to get the bot to paste the contents of the file deaths.txt

Comment: Does this also appy for other text without the "!"?

Comment: not sure i understand you there @AbdullahAlhariri

Comment: Have you tried using other strings instead of "!deaths"?

Comment: It could be the case that "!" is just the issue!

Comment: so should i use like /deaths?

Comment: used "/paste"
didn't get a response from bot either

Comment: Are you sure that the connection is right with the discord server and your code?

Comment: i believe so, the discord bot is online on the discord

Answer (score -1):

fixed it swapped
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

to

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).